# Confused by jQuery 'parent' scope on event trigger

Tags: jquery, scope, interaction

When a user clicks on a link, I'm trying to check if that link's container has a class of `active` assigned to it.

But I think I'm having a problem with scoping, as while the visual style is applied by the browser, the click isn't seeing that class assignment when it's triggered.

I've created a jsfiddle [replicating the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/markedup/F69nh/3/). Enlightenment much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$link` is out of scope for the annoynmous function inside your handler. You need to use `$(this)` inside the click handler instead:

```
$links.each( function(i) {
    $link = $(this);
    $link.click( function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('L' + i + ': ' + $(this).parent().hasClass('active'));
    });
});
```

See the [**updated jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/F69nh/4/).

---

You can also use event data to act as closures if you have to solve this without using `$(this)`, for example:

```
$links.each( function(i) {
    $link = $(this);
    $link.click({ link : $link }, function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //console.log('L' + i + ': ' + $(this).parent().hasClass('active'));
        e.data.link.parent();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Ben, much appreciated. I've not seen the 'data' approach before and like it, but are there any additional overheads with using 'data' compared to straight up $(this) reference?

Comment: Actually, using `data` would be slightly quicker, since you're not constructing a new jQuery object, you're passing in a reference to one that already exists.

Comment: The same result can be achieved using the native `var` keyword, and it's even simpler.

Comment: @BenM It's precisely the opposite, inside a function any variable declared with `var` only exists in the scope of this function. See my answer for details.

Comment: Yes, but in your example of global scope, `a` belongs to the `window` object when it doesn't need to. I know what you're saying, but it's better to use closures.

Comment: @BenM It's just an example to demonstrate how javascript scoping works... I mean, in your case, it's simpler to take advantage of the local scope. Moreover, be aware that your `$link` variable may overwrite another variable with the same name in a parent scope, due to the missing of the `var` keyword...

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use `on`

```
$controls.on("click", "a", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var theParent = $(this).parent();
    //if you need 'i' here it is
    var i = $.inArray(theParent[0], $controls);
    console.log('L' + i + ': ' + theParent.hasClass('active'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/F69nh/6/

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to use the `var` keyword to reduce the scope of your variable :

```
$links.each(function () {
    var $link = $(this);
    ...
});
```

Global scope demo :

```
var a = 1;
function f(v) { a = v; };
console.log(a); // 1
f(2);
console.log(a); // 2
```

Local scope demo :

```
var a = 1;
function f(v) { var a = v; };
console.log(a); // 1
f(2);
console.log(a); // 1
```

Check this [great post about javascript scoping](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting).

Answer (score 0):

Simplify your JavaScript like so:

```
var $controls = $('#controls li');
var $links = $('a', $controls);
var $control, $link;

$controls.each( function(i) {
    $control = $(this);
    if (i == 0) {
        $control.addClass('active');
    }
    console.log('C' + i + ': ' + $control.hasClass('active'));
});

$links.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('L' + $(this).index() + ': ' + $(this).parent().hasClass('active'));
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's another approach for a possible menu:
http://jsfiddle.net/earthdesigner/7uxcg/1/

The javascript portion:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('nav a').click(function(){
        $('nav li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    })  
});
```

Comment: Huh? How does that answer his question?!